# What is causing this ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' while using logisticRegr.fit(x_train, y_train)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm attempting to run a test_train_split and then use that to run a logistics regression analysis.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x = hotel_data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = hotel_data.iloc[:,-1]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
```

When I run the code

```
logisticRegr.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I get

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'CityHotel'
```

'CityHotel' refers to a type of hotel under the column 'hotel' from the dataset I'm using 'hotel_data'. The other option in that column is 'ResortHotel'.

Answer (score 2):

You have categorical variables in your data. *CityHotel* is one of the features of your data, but it is categorical. This means that the entries of this column are not numbers but categories (*strings* like "cat", "dog", "fish"). Your model does not recognise those as valid input and it complains --> `could not convert string to float` this means that the model does not accept strings as inputs and does not have a method to convert them into float.

There is a simple solution: **categorical variables encoding**. Search online as there are many different methods. You should choose the one that suits you the best. Normally, I would first compute the cardinality, aka the number of unique values under column *CityHotel* and then think which encoding method would be the best choice.